# Cannot sum sql query into single line

Tags: sql, sql-view

I have a view (using it to link into an Access 2016 Front-End thus the view). I am trying to sum 4 rows where each have a different status of Approved, In Progress, Rejected and Cancelled. The field I want to sum is Total_Cost.

Criteria is [Status] <> 'Rejected' and <> 'Cancelled'. Therefore, I want Approved and In progress to sum into 1.

The view is still showing 2 rows (Field ID is the primary key so want to show by ID). I have unselected the Output box for [Status]. This normally works in Access but I cannot get it to work in SQL. I have tried Group by, Where, Sum etc and nothing is working.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Smiddy

Comment: could you provide an example please ?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Aside: @a_horse_with_no_name, I was absolutely thinking of you when I wrote that Meta Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

The following query might help you or solve your question :

```
SELECT 
     ID, SUM(CASE 
          WHEN [Status] <> 'Rejected' AND [Status] <> 'Cancelled' 
          THEN Total_Cost 
          ELSE 0 END) AS yourTotal
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
```